# Non blocking timer in linux user space (in C)

Tags: c, timer, sleep, signals, nonblocking

Actually I want to implement non-blocking timer, when the timer expires a handler will be called and will do something (for now it prints data). I google and realized that [`timer_create`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html), [`timer_settimer`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_settime.2.html) are non-blocking timer. BUT still I've issue, I have to wait for my timer to expire (`sleep(MAX)` or `while(1) {;}`). But then if I'm calling my `start_timer` method with different "expiry" time, it should work accordingly, should not block other. e.g. here first time I'm calling timer, and expecting to call handler in 5 sec but before that 2nd call should print its data as, that interval I've given is 1sec only. And of course its not behaving same. Any idea?

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

typedef struct _data{
    char *name;
}data;


void handler(union sigval val)
{
    data *data_handler = val.sival_ptr;
    printf("Handler entered with value :%s\n", data_handler->name);
}

void mod_timer(timer_t timerid, struct sigevent sig, struct itimerspec in, struct itimerspec out)
{
    printf("mod_timer\n");
    timer_settime(timerid, 0, &in, &out);
    while(1)
        sleep(1);
    //delete the timer.
    timer_delete(timerid);
}

void start_timer(void* val, int interval)
{
    int Ret;
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_init( &attr );

    struct sched_param parm;
    parm.sched_priority = 255;
    pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attr, &parm);

    struct sigevent sig;
    sig.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD;
    sig.sigev_notify_function = handler;
//    sig.sigev_value.sival_int = val;
    sig.sigev_value.sival_ptr = val;
    sig.sigev_notify_attributes = &attr;

//create a new timer.
    timer_t timerid;
    Ret = timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &sig, &timerid);
    if (Ret == 0)
    {
        struct itimerspec in, out;
        in.it_value.tv_sec = 1;
        in.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;
        in.it_interval.tv_sec = interval;
        in.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;

       mod_timer(timerid, sig, in, out);
    }
}

void main()
{
//    start_timer(1, 5);
//    start_timer(2, 1);
    data handler_data1 = {"Handler Data 1"};
    data handler_data2 = {"Handler Data 2"};
    void *data1 = &handler_data1;
    void *data2 = &handler_data2;
    start_timer(data1, 5);
    start_timer(data2, 1);
}
```

Comment: Why not have a separate thread for timer?

Comment: What is your goal with this code? This seems more like a design flaw than a timer problem.

Comment: @Dave ya right, not exactly timer problem, my goal is as I said, I want to execute handler (perform task), after "interval" delay. For instance, from this code, data1 should be executed after 5 sec, and data2 after 1 sec. i.e. once I start execution in 1 sec data2 will be performed and after again 4 sec, data1.

Comment: @noMAD can you elaborate please, may be some pseudo-code will help

Comment: @noMAD,I tried with threading, creating thread in start_timer and thread method as mod_timer, but still l in start_timer I have to do pthread_join(thread_id), right? So that's again pausing execution of other call. (here data2). :(((

Comment: No no, no `join()`. Then the purpose of a thread running separately is wasted. Just let the thread start and keep checking for the timer to end. When it does, do a `pthread_exit()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`alarm`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/alarm) function to generate a signal, and the [`signal`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/signal) function to specify the handler to that signal.

Comment: The question is about how to use timer_ not alarm. Also alarm takes sec as arguments. What if the user need 1.1234567 sec?